# I've got  a pointer to an object. How do I call a function that expects a reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a function which takes a reference to an object:

```
void move(Ball& ball);
```

I have another function calling 'move()' which has a pointer to ball:

```
void foo(Ball* ball){
 //call move()
}
```

How is `foo()` supposed to pass ball to `move()`?

Should it be like:

```
move(*ball);
```

or:

```
move(ball);
```

or:

```
move(&ball);
```

Comment: Do you have a compiler? why not just test it out yourself. lazy bum.

Comment: Not that I disagree with doing a minimum of research yourself, but it's generally not a good idea to trust your C++ compiler to tell you what is or isn't legal. "it compiles" is not the same as "it is well-defined C++"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first one, move(*ball).

the second one, move(ball) tries to pass the pointer and the third one, move(&ball) tries to pass a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 6):

move(*ball);

Here's why.  You can think of a reference as basically taking a pointer to the object it is handed.  Thus you want the object itself, not a pointer.  If you call move(ball) you will be taking a reference (pointer) to the pointer, not the object.  Instead, move(*ball) dereferences the pointer and the reference then takes the pointer of that dereferenced object.

Answer (score 4):

With the * operator on a pointer you dereference it, thus obtaining a Ball object. Since you're actually passing your parameter to a function that accepts a Ball& (so a Ball reference) only the reference will be passed, and not the whole object. The right usage is:

```
move(*ball);
```

But I suggest you to name the variables in a way that "speaks" about their nature, so **`ballPtr`** or **`ball_ptr`** would be more appropriate and you will never forget about dereferencing it.

Answer (score 1):

the first one is correct that is move(*ball)
ball is a pointer pointing to the object , you need to dereference it, after dereferencing its the object that is pointed to by ball pointer.